# VB.net working splash screen

Tags: vb.net, splash-screen, onload-event

So I've been trying to work out how to get my splash screen working. When my program starts I'm going to add a number of checks and I've got a progress bar that I'm updating next to a little logo.

My problem is any code I call in the splash_load runs before my form displays? I added the splashscreen from Windows Forms > Splash Screen and I set it to the "startup form" in my application settings.

For now I'm performing a simple MySQL Connection test, but my splash screen doesn't display until the whole sub has finished running?

**splash.vb**

```
Public NotInheritable Class splash

    Private Sub splash_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        mysql.connectionTest()
    End Sub

End Class
```

**mysql.vb**

```
Public Shared Sub connectionTest()
        Using SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection(My.Settings.mtConnStr)
            Try
                SQLConnection.Open()
                MessageBox.Show("Connection OK!")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
                Application.Exit()
            Finally
                SQLConnection.Close()
            End Try

        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: You can go in for threading :
  Dim t As Thread
        t = New Thread(AddressOf Me.connectiontest
                       )
        t.Start()

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are calling the connectionTest in the Load event.  The form does not show until that event is completed.  You could move that one line of code to the Splash_Shown event instead, and it should process after the form is loaded and visible.

Comment: I moved it to the shown event but now all I can see is the form background and no text/images appear until after the connection test is complete.

Comment: You will probably also need to put the connectionTest in a separate thread, or use DoEvents (shudder).  Getting a form to update with text/images etc. is not an easy thing to do from a single thread.  For some info on the order that events are triggered, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d(v=vs.110).aspx